# method init in class Preferences cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, init

```
method init in class Preferences cannot be applied to given types;
required: String
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

and `Preferences.init();` is marked red in NetBeans

I do not know what the problem is?

When running I get the following error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: processing.app.Preferences.init
    at arduinojava.ArduinoJava.main(ArduinoJava.java:34)
Java Result: 1
```

Here is the code:

```
/*
* This class will get the input from arduino board and output
* the data to the scanner
* Code adopted from Silveira Neto
*/

package arduinojava;

import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import processing.app.Preferences;

/**
*
* @author kinley tshering
*/
public class ArduinoJava {

static InputStream input;
static OutputStream output;
static CommPortIdentifier portId;
static SerialPort port;

/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/

public static void main(String[] args) {
  //code application logic here

     Preferences.init();
     System.out.println("Using port: " + Preferences.get("serial.port"));
    try {
            portId = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(
                   Preferences.get("serial.port"));

          //port = (SerialPort)portId.open("serial talk", 4000);
          port = (SerialPort)portId.open("", 4500);
          input = port.getInputStream();
          output = port.getOutputStream();
           port.setSerialPortParams(Preferences.getInteger("serial.debug_rate"),
                  SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                  SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                  SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

          while(true){
                      while(input.available() > 0) {
                                   System.out.print((char)(input.read()));
                       }
           }
  }
  catch(gnu.io.NoSuchPortException nsp)  {
       System.err.println("ERROR: " + nsp.getMessage());
   }
  catch(gnu.io.UnsupportedCommOperationException usp)  {
       System.err.println("ERROR: " + usp.getMessage());
   }
   catch(gnu.io.PortInUseException pie)  {
       System.err.println("ERROR: Port " + port + " is already in use\nCLose the port and restart.");
   }
   catch(java.io.IOException ioe) {
       System.err.println("IO ERROR: " + ioe.getMessage() );
   }
   catch(Exception exe) {
       System.err.println("ERROR: Unexpected error occured \n" + exe.getMessage() );
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
method init in class Preferences cannot be applied to given types;
required: String
found: no arguments
```

it seems you don't have any method init() **without** parameters in `Preferences` class.

You need to call something like below:

```
Preferences.init("yourString");
```

NOTE: We don't know what `yourString` should be exactly while invoking `init()` method.

Comment: Now I get the following error: `init(String) has protected access in Preferences`?

Comment: @F4LLCON: Without seeing your Preferences class it is hard to suggest how to proceed. If init is protected, how are you directly invoking like a static method instead of creating instance of Preference and then call init() on that instance.

Comment: I just followed this `http://kinleyphycom.blogspot.nl/2009/04/connecting-arduino-and-java-in-windows.html` tutorial to connect my Arduino with NetBeans. I just copied the code and did the same as that tutorial, but I get this error. I have no clue where to look. only `init` is marked red now

Comment: it is, in the Preferences.java I see: `protected static void init(String commandLinePrefs) {`

Is this important? Because I can´t change it anyway. Locked

Comment: I get this error while running it: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - init(java.lang.String) has protected access in processing.app.Preferences
 at arduinojava.ArduinoJava.main(ArduinoJava.java:34)
Java Result: 1`

Comment: And while building it I get: `C:\Users\F4LLCON\Documents\NetBeansProjects\mpl\ArduinoJava\src\arduinojava\ArduinoJava.java:34: error: init(String) has protected access in Preferences
     Preferences.init(" ");
1 error
C:\Users\F4LLCON\Documents\NetBeansProjects\mpl\ArduinoJava\nbproject\build-impl.xml:915: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\F4LLCON\Documents\NetBeansProjects\mpl\ArduinoJava\nbproject\build-impl.xml:268: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)`

Comment: I found out that processing.app.Preferences; is missing from pde.jar. I can't find it anywhere....

Answer (score 0):

> method init in class Preferences cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: String found: no arguments

The error says it all, your init() method is expecting a String argument and you are passing none.

This 
     Preferences.init();

should be

```
 Preferences.init("pass a string argument here");
```